# Perform different operations on parallel streams generated by groupBy?

Tags: project-reactor, reactor

```
    KafkaReceiver.create(options).receive().groupBy(i-> Integer.parseInt(i.value())%2 ==0? "Even":"Odd").doOnNext(x ->
            System.out.println("Inside map the thread is " + Thread.currentThread().getName()))
            .flatMap(partitionFlux ->
            partitionFlux.publishOn(scheduler)
                    .concatMap(m -> writeBigQuery(m)
                            .doOnSuccess(r -> m.receiverOffset().commit())
                    .doOnError(e -> System.out.println("ErrorMono"+e.getStackTrace()))
                    .retry(3))).subscribe
            (System.out::println);
```

I want to write a method which gives me a tuple of FLUX(one with odd stream and another with even stream
Signature of the method looks like this:  private Tuple2<Flux<ReceiverRecord<Integer,String>>, Flux<ReceiverRecord<Integer,String>>> getTuple
(Flux<GroupedFlux<String,ReceiverRecord<Integer,String>>> flux)

Can someone help with the implementation of this?

Comment: Basically I want to get a tuple of Flux from this groupedFlux?

Comment: private Tuple2<Flux<ReceiverRecord<Integer,String>>, Flux<ReceiverRecord<Integer,String>>> getTuple
            (Flux<GroupedFlux<String,ReceiverRecord<Integer,String>>> flux)  method like this